# Copying pages from PDF ignoring blanks pages iTextSharp

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext

I am trying to loop through a PDF document with iTextSharp and remove all blank pages.
I have the code to check each page is not blank and write it to a new PDF but I'm getting the error "The document has no pages" when closing the new document. However the file that gets created in the folder does have a file size that I would expect.

Here is my current code:

```vb
Dim reader As PdfReader = New PdfReader(strSourceFile)
Dim raf As RandomAccessFileOrArray = New RandomAccessFileOrArray(strSourceFile)
Dim document As Document = New Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1))
Dim writer As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, New FileStream(saver.FileName, FileMode.Create))
document.Open()
Dim page As PdfImportedPage = Nothing

Dim cb As Byte()

For i As Integer = 1 To reader.NumberOfPages()

    cb = reader.GetPageContent(i, raf)
    If cb.Length > 150 Then

        page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i)

    End If

Next

document.Close() 'This is where the error occurs.
writer.Close()
raf.Close()
reader.Close()
```

Comment: What is this `bs` you close there?

Comment: You read a page but I don't see anything related to writing it in that `if`.

Comment: The BS is left over code, i'll remove it.

Comment: Ok. Now the problem @usr2564301 mentioned remains: You import the page into the new document (as form XObject) but you don't put that XObject onto any page of the new document. Thus, just like the error message says, the document has no pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is as @usr2564301 mentioned in a comment: You import the page into the new document (as form XObject) but you don't put that XObject onto any page of the new document.

To put it there, simply extend your `if` clause like this:

```
If cb.Length > 150 Then

    page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i)
    writer.DirectContentUnder.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0)
    document.NewPage()

End If
```

There are some disadvantages to this solution, though: The page is imported as form Xobject and that XObject is pasted onto the current page in the target document. But if the page dimensions differ (A4 here, LETTER there, or portrait here, landscape there), parts of the page likely are lost. Furthermore, importing a page as XObject into a `PdfWriter` only copies the regular page contents but ***not*** annotations (like form fields) and similar extra stuff.

Instead, you should use a `PdfCopy` for this:

```
Dim reader As PdfReader = New PdfReader(strSourceFile)
Dim raf As RandomAccessFileOrArray = New RandomAccessFileOrArray(strSourceFile)
Dim document As Document = New Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1))
Dim copy As PdfCopy = New PdfCopy(document, New FileStream(strDestFile, FileMode.Create))
document.Open()
Dim page As PdfImportedPage = Nothing

Dim cb As Byte()

For i As Integer = 1 To reader.NumberOfPages()

    cb = reader.GetPageContent(i, raf)
    If cb.Length > 150 Then

        page = copy.GetImportedPage(reader, i)
        copy.AddPage(page)

    End If

Next

document.Close()
raf.Close()
reader.Close()
```

This copies the complete pages as they are.

Comment: Hi mkl. After some trial and error and looking through some comments on some non-accepted answers I came round to using your top method. This worked but also had the side effect of slightly inflating the size of the file as well for some odd reason. Your second solution is much better as the file size drops as expected and will keep the other features you mention. Thanks!